# Empty view controller in distribution mode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have got a view controller that is displayed nicely and works fine in the simulator AND while debuggin on various deivces (ipads and iphones of different generation - iPhone only app)

But when downloaded from the shop this view remains empty. It remains empty too when the IPA boundle is made for beta testers.

The view controller is poped, displayed and animated. The navigation bar appears and I can navigate back to the calling view controller. All other view controllers of the small app work nicely.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

I don't know if this is allowed, but if it is I could provide a link to the store for anybody who would like to test it. It is a free app.

It might be some very stupid thing because this was my very first app some time ago. However, it used to work fine (afaik).

Update: 
When installed from the store or from an AdHoc boundle the view is displayed as it is defined in the XIB file. In that file it is empty. 
When installed for debug on simulator or device, I do see the two controls, which are generated programmatically. They even work properly. 
This is the creation code:

```
#define kSegmentedControlHeight 40.0
#define kLabelHeight            20.0
#define kLeftMargin             20.0
#define kTopMargin              20.0
#define kRightMargin            20.0
#define kTweenMargin            10.0

- (void)createControls
{
    NSArray *segmentBlendeTextContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"ganz", @"halb", @"drittel", nil];
    NSArray *segmentISOTextContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"ISO", @"ASA", @"DIN", @"GOST", nil];

    CGFloat yPlacement;
    CGRect frame;


    // label
    yPlacement += (kTweenMargin * 2.0) + kSegmentedControlHeight;
    frame = CGRectMake( kLeftMargin,
                       yPlacement,
                       self.view.bounds.size.width - (kRightMargin * 2.0),
                       kLabelHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:[SettingsViewController labelWithFrame:frame title:@"Blendstufen:"]];

    fStopSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentBlendeTextContent];
    yPlacement += kTweenMargin + kLabelHeight;
    frame = CGRectMake( kLeftMargin,
                       yPlacement,
                       self.view.bounds.size.width - (kRightMargin * 2.0),
                       kSegmentedControlHeight);
    fStopSegmentedControl.frame = frame;
    fStopSegmentedControl.tintColor = theGlobals.inBarColor;
    [fStopSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(fStopSegmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    fStopSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    // Hier wird der Default gesetzt !!!
    fStopSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

    [self.view addSubview:fStopSegmentedControl];

    //Setze Control für Blendestufen-Wert
    [fStopSegmentedControl setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:theGlobals.fStopSetting.integerValue - 1];   

    // label
    yPlacement += (kTweenMargin * 2.0) + kSegmentedControlHeight;
    frame = CGRectMake( kLeftMargin,
                       yPlacement,
                       self.view.bounds.size.width - (kRightMargin * 2.0),
                       kLabelHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:[SettingsViewController labelWithFrame:frame title:@"Normensystem Film/Sensor:"]];

    yPlacement += kTweenMargin + kLabelHeight;
    isoSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentISOTextContent];
    frame = CGRectMake( kLeftMargin,
                       yPlacement,
                       self.view.bounds.size.width - (kRightMargin * 2.0),
                       kSegmentedControlHeight);
    isoSegmentedControl.frame = frame;
//  isoSegmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    isoSegmentedControl.tintColor = theGlobals.inBarColor;
    [isoSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(isoSegmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    isoSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

    // Setze Wert für Blendstufen
    isoSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = theGlobals.isoSetting.integerValue - 1;

    [self.view addSubview:isoSegmentedControl];

    //Setze Control für ISO-Wert
    [isoSegmentedControl setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:theGlobals.isoSetting.integerValue - 1];   // 1 noch in Variable ändern !!!

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Einstellungen";

//  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:32.0/255.0 green:32.0/255.0 blue:32.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];   

    [self createControls];  // create the showcase of controls
}
```

Update 2: The difference is in the build configuration. When I build for "run" locally but use the "distribution" configuration rather than the "development" configuration then I observe the same behaviour on the device: Blank view controller. But on the simulator I do see the controls, just misplaced further down. 
So for the moment I guess that the controls are part of the view on the device too but displayed further down below the bottom line of the screen.

Update 3: Getting closer ... 
It comes down to the float yPlacement. In release mode, the debugger cannot display its contents. It is mentioned in the debugger window where the varialbes are displayed but it is not resolved. When printing its decription I get:

```
Printing description of yPlacement:
(CGFloat) yPlacement = <variable not available>
```

So in the end it seems to come down to some compiler error in conjunction with optimization flags that may be set for debug (-O0) but not for release/distribution (-Os). Or it is simply caused by the fact that debuging symbols are stripped off in the release and distribution versions. 
The frame variable, however, I can see properly. Aparently the values that are fed in via yPlacement are different.

Update 5: Solution found. Issue fixed. I'll do some further testing and if I am right here I'll post an answer. BTW - it is there in the code. You can see it.

Comment: Is the nib actually in your project? Sometimes you can accidentally delete a xib and not notice for quite a while as it is already on your test device and sim.

Comment: I' will check upon that. I guess I check first whether it is part of the target and included in the copy or compile (?) items and if it is then I double check whether it is acutally included in the *.ipa. Right?

Comment: Easiest thing to try is to delete the current build from the simulator. If this then reproduces the error then it probably points to the xib not being present in the build.

Comment: Well, it is not that easy. Deleting it from the simulator does not make a change. Actually I a working on a blank mac. :) I have had a similar thing before with some image resource. Deleting the app from the simulator did not make a change. But at that time the file was missnig on every real device, which it does not in this case.

Comment: So with a fresh install to the sim you are seeing the correct behaviour?

Comment: Hmm... it is included in the target, build settings and part of the *.app in the *.ipa file. In IB the view is empty as displayed and the two controls on it are generated programmatically. They are not displayed on the device when boundled for distribution or AdHoc. I'll update the question with this detail.

Comment: Yes, with a fresh install I see correct behaviour. Even if I delete the app from the simulators "file system", and install it freshly I do see correct behaviour. Please see my comment above.

Comment: Are you running the same version sim as you are on the devices getting the release/adhoc builds?

Comment: Well, no. The simulator is on the mac and uses x86 architecture. But yes, I build both from identical sources. It is not only a simulator/device issue. The app works fine on my debug devices when I build them for debug.

Comment: I meant sim version e.g. iOS SDK. Do you have different targets for adhoc/release and debug?

Comment: Well, getting closer ... It must be somewhere within my configuration. I changed the configuration for "build" from "development" to "distribution". Which means that I may not be able to debug it ("failed to get process" - naturally as get-task-allow is set to false). And now it shows the same issue when running on the device. And on the simulator, with these settings, the controls are displayed but much further down than they should be.

Comment: 1 Target in the project. 3 Build configurations, Development, Distribution and Release. All Build configuration SDKs are set to "latest iOS 6.1". You could be on the right track anyway. Because an earlier version in the store with older SDK and xcode did run properly.

Answer (score 0):

It is too obvious to see.

```
CGFloat yPlacement;

yPlacement += (kTweenMargin * 2.0) + kSegmentedControlHeight;
```

yPlacement is defined as local variable but not initialized. The next thing hat happens is rather than assiging a value the new value is added to the variable with the `+=` operator.

For some reason in debug mode without any optimization `-O0` the variable happend to reside in zeroed memory and therefore had the value 0 as if it were properly initilized. But it was not! As a result everything worked fine so far, which was quite misleading.

In distribution and release configurations the optimization was set to smallest/fastest which is `-Os`. In that mode I was luck to have 0 values in the non-initialized varialbe. Therefore the new value was added to some random value which then happens to result in having the controls placed somewhere outside the visible area.

Thanks to everybody for listening and discussing the issue. In the end it led me to finding the error.